# How to get only the schema of the database into a dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

How to load only the schema of the tables into a dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fillschema.aspx)

Comment: This gives me schema of all tables in the dataset but How do I get relations between tables ?

Answer (score 3):

Do a query that normaly would return your data and add a where clause so that no rows are returned.

Comment: Even with calling FillSchema, if the query you use doesn't return 0 rows, it's taking longer than it needs. Thanks for the (subtle) point!